# Не появился значок wi-fi после установки ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Установил Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS на ноутбук HP. Не появился значок Wi-Fi вверху на Ubuntu Desktop. Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, драйвер не установлен. Попробуйте так:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmwar
```

Comment: ни одна из комманд не прошла(

Comment: Что значит "не прошла"?

Comment: ну не найден пишет или ещё что-то. Установка вобщем не произошла.

Comment: Какая карточка? Покажите вывод lspci -vnn | grep Network

Comment: что конкретно на до ввести в терминал? я новичёк в ubuntu

Comment: lspci -vnn | grep Network

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49444/discussion-between-carapuz-and-sven).

Comment: выдал 13:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот эту ссылку https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Realtek-8723DE-wifi-module-amp-Bluetooth-Linux-driver/td-p/6477307, возможно это то что вам нужно

1. Убедитесь, что у вас установлен git. Вы можете установить git с помощью apt install git или через синаптический / программный менеджер. Если вы хотите использовать dkms для создания и установки драйвера, убедитесь, что dkms также установлен. Вы можете загрузить и установить с помощью следующих команд в терминале:

~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install git dkms

2. Драйвер RTL8723DE находится в расширенной ветви git. Так

Откройте терминал:

: ~ $ cd Загрузки

: ~ $ git clone -b extended --single-branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
неофициальный
: ~ $ cd rtlwifi_new

Теперь либо вы можете запустить:
:~$ cd Downloads

:~$ git clone -b extended --single-branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
unofficial
:~$ cd rtlwifi_new

Теперь вы можете запустить

:~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ make
:~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ sudo make install

ИЛИ используйте dkms для создания модулей и управления ими:

:~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ sudo dkms add ../rtlwifi_new
:~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ sudo dkms build rtlwifi-new/0.6
:~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
:~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ sudo modprobe -v rtl8723de ant_sel=2

^^ Это должно сработать. Если отображается ошибка прошивки, перезагрузитесь и будет работать. Убедитесь, что у вас установлены linux-заголовки для соответствующего ядра (ядер) и пакетов, необходимых для сборки.

Для меня ant_sel = 2 показывает максимальное усиление сигнала WiFi. Итак, я добавил следующие строки в отдельный файл conf:

:~$ sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" >> /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf'